# How can AbsoluteTimes be split by date faster?

Tags: date-and-time

I have data where the date is stored as an `AbsoluteTime`. Here's a dummy dataset:

```
sampleData=Transpose[{#,Range[Length[#]]}]&[Range[AbsoluteTime[{2012,10,01}],
    AbsoluteTime[{2013,09,30}],60]];
```

I want to split it by date, so I use:

```
splitData=SplitBy[sampleData,DateList[First[#]][[;;3]]&];
```

This takes ~22 s on my machine. Often I have bigger data sets than this. Is there a faster way to get `splitData`?

Comment: Ooh... `DateList` is a killer. I once wrote something similar to what you need. Let me try to dig it up.

Answer (score 6):

When you have your date/time in `AbsoluteTime` and need to compare two dates repeatedly/several times, it is faster to count increments of seconds/minutes/hours than use `DateList` in each.

For simplicitly, I'll assume that the list is sorted by date and that the first element corresponds to the earliest date. We'll take our reference time as 00:00 hrs on this date. Then, splitting the data by date is as simple as:

```
With[{start = AbsoluteTime@DateList[sampleData[[1, 1]]][[;; 3]]},
    splitData2 = GatherBy[sampleData, Quotient[#[[1]] - start, 86400] &]
]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* 0.055087, Null *)
```

Comparing this with your `DateList` solution (note that I've corrected the test function in `SplitBy` to actually do what you described):

```
splitData = SplitBy[sampleData,DateList[First@#][[;;3]]&]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {19.206535, Null} *)

splitData == splitData2
(* True *)
```

Comment: +1. But it might not be as simple as that, in general - there are leap seconds and the like.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Absolutely. Leap seconds are not accounted for in this (and other date-time oddities). I suppose if OP's data has something like that, then a JLink/Java approach similar to what you've answered before might be a better solution.

Comment: I might add some answer like that later. I happened to have recently used Java / reloader again for a similar practical problem ( I was helping friends to parse a 4Gb log file from their server, using Mathematica, and going to Java for date parsing was a crucial point - everything else I was able to do reasonably well within Mathematica). And by the way, my recent work has been on Mac, so I finally fixed the reloader for Mac too (at least it works on my system now, while used to produce the same error that you have reported before).

Comment: Oh, that's good! Is the updated version in your answer here? BTW, a lot of your tools might be better on github, which can host the latest version... I know you like gists, but it's not easy to search through them :)

Comment: Re: updated version - not yet, but will be soon, I just need to repost it. Re: GitHub - yes, I do have a few repos there, and I agree that it is convenient. If only I could finish my stuff, it would have search built in the system, on Mathematica-side. It has been very close to completion, for several months now. The time is very scarce resource these days for me, though - you could have noticed it by how much I reduced my activity here in the last several months. But I still hope to get that stuff out soon.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin we can but hope that we will be recompensated for your (noticed) absence by amazing features in an anniversary edition ;-)

Comment: @YvesKlett Well, I do hope that the stuff I am currently working on will enter into V10, but how are we to get it all done to meet the deadlines is currently beyond me ... Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is another option using `Floor`:

```
(splitData=SplitBy[sampleData,DateList[First[#]][[;;3]]&])//AbsoluteTiming//First
(splitData2=SplitBy[sampleData,Floor[#[[1]]/86400.]&])//AbsoluteTiming//First
(splitData3=GatherBy[sampleData,Floor[#[[1]]/86400.]&])//AbsoluteTiming//First
```

> 9.618810
>
> 2.227605
>
> 0.056786

```
splitData == splitData2 == splitData3
```

> True

PS: use 86400. instead of 86400 make all the difference for `splitData3`